# Oracle select statement performance

Tags: database, oracle

i have the following select statement :

> ```
> (
>   SELECT CAL_DATE,BUS_DAY
>   FROM risk_mart.vw_calendar_t5
>   WHERE type = 'RPC'
>   AND BUS_DAY BETWEEN 0 AND 1
> ) CAL
>  WHERE t.cal_date         = cal.cal_date
> ```

It selects all the dates and then filters them `between` 0 and 1 (displays only two dates e.g. '22-OCT-12','19-OCT-12').

Now, i can re-write that manually as

> WHERE t.cal_date in ('22-OCT-12','19-OCT-12')

The difference is performance. The first example i get a return back within 90 seconds and the second example, i get it within 10 seconds. Why?.

How can i improve the first statement/rewrite it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FROM
(
  SELECT CAL_DATE,BUS_DAY
  FROM risk_mart.vw_calendar_t5
  WHERE type = 'RPC'
  AND BUS_DAY BETWEEN 0 AND 1
) CAL --inner view
 WHERE t.cal_date         = cal.cal_date --join of table t and CAL
```

Now ,this is your first query .In this you are first retrieving the records into an inner view CAL which takes some amount of time .And after that you join `t.cal_date         = cal.cal_date` which will again take some amount of time (TOTAL 90Sec).

Now ,here is the second query .

```
FROM T
WHERE t.cal_date      IN ('22-OCT-12','19-OCT-12');
```

In this case ,you dint use the inner view ,so you have somehow managed to get the `dates` directly and use that in your where condition(*HARDCODED*) .This was you have reduce the processing time of the inner view (CAL) and the join with the CAL table with table t.

Answer (score 0):

Let's re-write you code like this?

```
    Case 1:
    from
        Cal
    Inner join 
    t on cal.cal_date = t.cal.date

    case 2:
      from t
      where t.cal_date in (....)
```

Select statement first step is always the "FROM" clause. In the case 2, The first step is always the FROM clause. In your case, this is pretty straight-forward, because there's only one table, and there aren't any complicated joins to worry about.

In the case 1,a query with joins, these are evaluated in this first step. The joins are assembled to decide which rows to retrieve, with the ON clause conditions being the criteria for deciding which rows to join from each table. The result of the FROM clause is an intermediate result. You could think of this as a temporary table, consisting of combined rows which satisfy all the join conditions.

That's why case 1 takes longer time than case 2.